# is it possible to reload avalonDock layout on demand e.g. via menu command?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpftoolkit, avalondock, xceed

```
 <xcad:DockingManager Name="myDockingManager" AnchorablesSource="{Binding FooterTools}" DocumentsSource="{Binding MainWindowTools}"
                            ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ActiveDocumentConverter}}"
                            avBehav:AvalonDockLayoutSerializer.LoadLayoutCommand="{Binding AdLayout.LoadLayoutCommand}"                                 avBehav:AvalonDockLayoutSerializer.SaveLayoutCommand="{Binding AdLayout.SaveLayoutCommand}">
```

In another place I got command that I want to load default layout:

ViewModel command:

```
  private RelayCommand _loadDefaultLayoutCommand;
    public RelayCommand LoadDefaultLayoutCommand
    {
        get 
        {
            return _restoreDefaultLayoutCommand ?? (_loadDefaultLayoutCommand= new RelayCommand(() => LoadDefaultLayout())

            ); 
        }
    }


private object LoadDefaultLayout()
    {
       ;//AdLayout.LoadDefaultLayoutCommand.Execute();
       //unfortunately I cannot invoke above command since I need to convey AvalonDockManager as a parameter which is impossible since ViewModel does not know it.

    }
```

I got AvalonDockViewModel property defined like this:

```
  public AvalonDockLayoutViewModel AdLayout
    {
        get { return _avalonDockLayout ?? (_avalonDockLayout = new AvalonDockLayoutViewModel()); }
    }
```

I would like to invoke command from ViewModel wich would update View
I thought that behaviors can be used for as a communication bridge between View and ViewModel.

For loading layouat and saving I used behaviors, e.g. for Load layout I used behavior like this:

```
private static void OnLoadLayoutCommandChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var framworkElement = obj as FrameworkElement;    
        // Remove the handler if it exist to avoid memory leaks

        if (framworkElement != null)
        {
            framworkElement.Loaded  -= OnFrameworkElementLoaded;

            var command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
            if (command != null)
            {
                // the property is attached so we attach the Drop event handler
                framworkElement.Loaded += OnFrameworkElementLoaded;
            }
        }
    }
```

It was quite logical since I have frameworkElement Load event.

Is it possible to use behavior mechanism or another to load default layout on demand e.g. as in my case on menu command?